# How to interact between two Azure tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have two Azure subscriptions,

- subscription (sub 1) I have hosted the Web Application and
- subscription (sub 2) has Azure AD

The sub 1 Web app needs to interact with the sub 2 Azure AD for operations. Due to some concerns we are not ready to open the ports or AD to internet. And we are planning to use power shell remoting, what are the options azure provides.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Azure subscriptions are hierarchically *under* an Azure AD tenant.
So your structure is most likely:

- Azure AD tenant 1

  - Sub 1 (contains a Web App)
- Azure AD tenant 2

  - Sub 2

In order for any app to do operations on an Azure AD tenant through Microsoft Graph API, an application must be registered in that tenant.
So what you can do:

1. Register an application in Azure AD tenant 2
2. Add a client secret/certificate to the app registration
3. Set required permissions in API permissions tab to Microsoft Graph API (choose between Delegated / Application permissions depending if your app will call the API on behalf of the user or as the app itself)
4. Consent to the permissions (this will require an Application/Global Admin to click the Grant admin consent button)
5. In your Web App, use the app credentials to acquire an access token and call the Microsoft Graph API

Comment: Hi @juunas, thank you for providing solution. will follow it and update you on the same.